# STOP Auto Localization of DateTime when Serializing/Deserializing with WCF Service and DataTable

Tags: c#, wcf, datetime, serialization

I can't figure this out and it's driving me nuts. To why a data type object does this is beyond me. I feel the designated types to handle timezones would suffice. Regardless, here is my setup. I have a WCF Service that feeds a serialized DataTable to my app. The data is input through a web interface. If I put 12/12/2014 11:00 AM into the database, it will strictly return 12/12/2014 12:00 PM in the data table to my app through the web service.

HOW DO I STOP THIS!?

Chain of events:

1. Login into the web interface, either choose to perform a task now (passes DateTime.Now) or at a later date (Parses a string representation of the date time constants chosen by the user). I am storing the timezone in a separate column.
   Note: DateTime.Now will NOT auto localize by the serializer, the other WILL.
2. The task is set correctly. All dates reflect correctly in the database. There are no discrepancies yet.
3. The task gets performed at the correct time set. Because I am handling the differences in times zones these tasks are set to perform in. This is working without a hitch. Tasks are performed when they should be.
4. Look at the phone. The time is wrong. I break point, and the data is incorrect coming from the web service in a datatable that has been serialized and deserialized. It will be an hour off (CMT to EST).

I've tried changing the kind in various places and nothing works.

I want what I've put into the database exactly as it's displayed. I handle timezone conversions in the database logic through simple arithmetic. There is no need for this automation.

For such an old issue, I'm sick of digging through mounds of work arounds, non of which work or have resolutions that explain well enough what to do and how to handle this.

Comment: `I've tried changing the kind in various places and nothing works` <-- can you detail what you did try? One common method of addressing this issue is to set `DateTime.Kind` property to Utc immediately after pulling the `DateTime` from the database. You would then need to convert the DateTime to your local time before displaying it to the client. However if both the server and client were in the *same* timezone you wouldnt expect the behaviour youre observing. Does your server and client live in different timezones?

Comment: I tried setting DateTime.Kind before submitting the value to the database. Then I tried on the App where I'm trying to display a TimeSpan of how long ago the message was set to display. It seems to me I would have to set Kind somewhere in between. To me that means the WCF Webservice that returns a DataTable. I have not tried iterating through the table and setting the column Kind then return the modified table. Personally this seems to be an expensive work around if that would fix the issue. Perhaps I'm mistaken though and should give it a try.

Comment: setting before the database definitely wont do anything; that field is not saved. the issue is after you read it out from the database it will have `DateTime.Kind` equal to `Unspecified` and you want it to be `Utc` (or so the convention goes). So yes you should give this a try (will not be expensive)

Comment: @wal something around the lines of this?

`Int32 upperBound = (output.Rows.Count - 1);

for (Int32 i = upperBound; (i >= 0);  i--)
{
    DateTime showAfter = (DateTime)output.Rows[i]["ShowAfter"];
    DateTime showBefore = (DateTime)output.Rows[i]["ShowBefore"];

    showAfter = DateTime.SpecifyKind(showAfter, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    showBefore = DateTime.SpecifyKind(showBefore, DateTimeKind.Utc);

    output.Rows[i]["ShowAfter"] = showAfter;
    output.Rows[i]["ShowBefore"] = showBefore;
}`

Comment: Did not work :( The time was still an hour ahead when displaying on the phone. Database says 9:20 AM, the phone shows 10:20 AM. The database resides in Texas (CMT) and I'm currently in New York EST so the difference makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I got it though it took a lot of adjustments. This is also for my specific setup and may not apply to everyone.

My setup:
Date times are passed to a database from a web interface in the same timezone that the database resides. A Windows Service running in the same timezone loops and pulls out task according to the show after field. This data is then pull from a phone app in any timezone and displaying the value in the form of how long ago Eg 1 minute ago, 2 hours ago etc. The phone app is the only one interfacing with a WCF service. Since the Windows Service resides on the same server, it does not require any middle man.

First on the website when inputting these "tasks" the date time is obtained by the following.

```
Double selectedTimezone = 0D;
Double offsetTimezone = 0D;

TimeZoneInfo timezoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.Local;

selectedTimezone = Double.Parse(DDL_EndTimezone.SelectedValue.ToString());

/* Obtain the timezone offset for server to user. 
   For me this is -1: -6 (CST) to -5 (EST) */

offsetTimezone = (timezoneInfo.BaseUtcOffset.TotalHours - selectedTimezone);

/* Parse the date time from the selected user 
   inputs. */

if (!chkSendMessageNow.Checked)
    start = DateTime.Parse(txtBeginDate.Text + " " + cmdBeginHour.SelectedValue.ToString() + ":" + cmdBeginMinute.SelectedValue.ToString() + ":" + "00");
else
    start = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + " " + DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString() + ":" + DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString() + ":" + "00");
end = DateTime.Parse(txtEndDate.Text + " " + DDL_EndHour.SelectedValue.ToString() + ":" + DDL_EndMin.SelectedValue.ToString() + ":" + "00");

/* Ensure these are "local" kind. I quote because 
   this is local time for user, not where the 
   site is hosted. */

start = DateTime.SpecifyKind(start, DateTimeKind.Local);
end = DateTime.SpecifyKind(end, DateTimeKind.Local);

/* Convert the start and end to UTC from 
   the timezone of the user with the 
   adjusted server to user timezone 
   offset. */

start = start.AddHours(offsetTimezone).AddHours(-1 * selectedTimezone);
end = end.AddHours(offsetTimezone).AddHours(-1 * selectedTimezone);

/* Specify this is UTC. */

start = DateTime.SpecifyKind(start, DateTimeKind.Utc);
end = DateTime.SpecifyKind(end, DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

Now those are saved to the database.

On the server in my WCF service I pull the DataTable but adjust the DateTime column(s) before returning the output to be serialized as follows.
This step is probably not necessary and is residual from previous attempts. But I'm not messing with it because it's working.

```
Int32 upperBound = (output.Rows.Count - 1);

DateTime showAfter = DateTime.MinValue;
DateTime showBefore = DateTime.MinValue;

for (Int32 i = upperBound; (i >= 0); i--)
{
    showAfter = (DateTime)output.Rows[i]["ShowAfter"];
    showBefore = (DateTime)output.Rows[i]["ShowBefore"];

    showAfter = DateTime.SpecifyKind(showAfter, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    showBefore = DateTime.SpecifyKind(showBefore, DateTimeKind.Utc);

    output.Rows[i]["ShowAfter"] = showAfter;
    output.Rows[i]["ShowBefore"] = showBefore;
}
```

Finally in the app for display the correctly localized time when deserialized. I do the following.

```
DateTime showAfter = DateTime.MinValue;

showAfter = Convert.ToDateTime(_dataTable.Rows[position]["ShowAfter"]);
showAfter = DateTime.SpecifyKind(showAfter, DateTimeKind.Utc);
showAfter = showAfter.ToLocalTime();
```